# QT4 open source project to build reusable components

Tags: json, qt, user-interface, qt4

Are there any opensource project to build reusable GUI components in QT4 with extra connection informaition saved in a JSON file? Qt designer lets you build a dialog and connect signals and slots together and save the results as a UI file. I am looking for a project that would extend this to build components that you could easily plugin into a c++ or pyside application. An example would be to build a playcontrol for a movie player with all the start, stop, rewind, fastforward buttons. Then in the application you just load the UI file or perhaps a JSON file with extra input and outputs for callbacks.

Comment: What's wrong with `QWidget` subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

leeg, what you are talking about doing with JSON is fairly extensive. I have to agree with Stefan's comment that modeling your custom widgets as subclasses of QWidget is the correct approach.

You can easily drop in the classes, so to speak, into any Qt GUI application. I use this technique frequently when creating new GUI elements not already present in the standard Qt GUI library. You can set layouts (vertical and horizontal) and then nest widgets in the widgets to design complexly behaving widgets. From there, you can create custom slots and signals for handling different events.

For example, you mentioned a player control for a movie player with a start, stop, rewind, and fast forward button. You would need to create a containing widget and then add a horizontal layout to your containing widget. Then you can add buttons for start, stop, rewind, and fast forward. If you want images for your buttons, you can set the button images on the buttons themselves. Then you could emit signals for start, stop, rewind, and fast forward. In the calling object, you would then connect slots to each respective signal.

This skeleton should help you get started:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

class PlayerControl : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    signals:
        void start();
        void stop();
        void rewind();
        void fastForward();

    private slots:
        void startClicked();
        void stopClicked();
        void rewindClicked();
        void fastForwardClicked();

    public:
        PlayerControl(QWidget *parent);
        ~PlayerControl();

    private:
        QPushButton startButton;
        QPushButton stopButton;
        QPushButton rewindButton;
        QPushButton fastForwardButton;
}

void PlayerControl::PlayerControl(QWidget *parent)
{
    // do setup here
    connect(startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startClicked()));
    connect(stopButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stopClicked()));
    connect(rewindButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(rewindClicked()));
    connect(fastForwardButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(fastForwardClicked()));
}

void PlayerControl::~PlayerControl()
{
    // clean up
}

void PlayerControl::startClicked()
{
    emit start();
}

void PlayerControl::stopClicked()
{
    emit stop();
}

void PlayerControl::rewindClicked()
{
    emit rewind();
}

void PlayerControl::fastForwardClicked()
{
    emit fastForward();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what I am asking is more about this part   >In the calling object, you would then connect slots to each respective signal. < I am looking for a way to create plugin-in like gui components by saving the connections of slots and signals.

Comment: While what you are saying is theoretically possible, but it would take a lot of time and energy to perfect. You would need to either use a lexical analyzer and write your own parser or use a library like QJson and parse the JSON. However, you'd still need to come up with a way to interpret these JSON files and dynamically create slots/signals based on the JSON definition. Essentially, there would be a lot of overhead with this approach. It could theoretically be done, but I wouldn't recommend it.